# Programatically generate order with custom order#

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, programmatically, edit-order

I'm using the code available [here](http://pastebin.com/8cft4d8v) to generate orders programmatically (importing from an older in-house system) and its actually working quite well. I've made some changes to check/create customers as needed, but it makes the orders just fine with one exception. I'd like to set the order number of these imported orders to match the number they had in the old system (a simple 4 to 6 digit number) without affecting magento's normal order numbering (these imported orders will be in a different "store" from new orders anyway).

I've tried a few variations for setting the IncrementID right before saving the order, but nothing seems to stick.

Some of the things I've tried:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->setIncrementId('test1234');

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getEntityType('order')
    ->setIncrementId('test1234');
```

Comment: Magento automatically set an increment id if this one hasn't been defined. See `_beforeSave` in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`. Are you sure you setting it properly? Can you paste the code you're executing?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a custom increment ID? If all you're trying to do is create a reference between the new system and old system, perhaps you might be better off creating a new column to store the old ID, letting Magento generate its own increment IDs. Just trying to approach the problem from a different angle.

Comment: I have to agree with Agop. I'd recommend maintaining Magento's internal increment and use a custom column to associate IDs between the two datasets.

Comment: Problem is, adding a custom field to the order is going to require permanent changes to the DB schema & a module/plugin to display that in the admin, vs a one-time change on import to alter the saved order number. I'm also not looking to change the increment system, I want to keep that as-is for all future orders, I just want to override the IncrementID for these imported orders.